# What is the most efficient way to convert this JavaScript object of objects to a more useful structure?

Tags: javascript, json, database, object

For example, I currently have a few objects that output to:

```
{
    "location": {
        "category": "Data_Set_1",
        "categoryID": "66e711cb-81ad-5e22-9fc7-910283924442"
    },
    "data_objects": {
        "dataEntryNumber": "0010",
        "data": {
            "value": 1.4593582153320312,
            "timestamp": "null"
        }
    }
}
{
    "location": {
        "category": "Data_Set_2",
        "categoryID": "2ec5e0c1-b839-59a6-8fd5-b09468d6cdd7"
    },
    "data_objects": {
        "dataEntryNumber": "0010",
        "data": {
            "value": 1.4593582153320312,
            "timestamp": "null"
        }
    }
}
{
    "location": {
        "category": "Data_Set_1",
        "categoryID": "66e711cb-81ad-5e22-9fc7-910283924442"
    },
    "data_objects": {
        "dataEntryNumber": "0010",
        "data": {
            "value": 1.4593582153320312,
            "timestamp": "null"
        }
    }
}
{
    "location": {
        "category": "Data_Set_3",
        "categoryID": "b905ae3d-1a41-5659-b15e-f305588a0afa"
    },
    "data_objects": {
        "dataEntryNumber": "0010",
        "data": {
            "value": 1.4593582153320312,
            "timestamp": "null"
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I have a 13 different data sets (ex: Data_Set_1, Data_Set_2, etc.) that appear somewhat randomly and more than once in this large set of multiple repeated objects. Each data set has around 6000 data entry points (dataEntryNumber: 0010, dataEntryNumber 0016, etc.).

How would I parse through this data to fit the format of:

```
{
    "category": "Data_Set_1",
    "categoryID": "66e711cb-81ad-5e22-9fc7-910283924442"
    data: {
        "0001": {
            "value": 1.42343432,
            "timestamp": "null"
        }
        "0002": {
            "value: 1.424234255,
            "timestamp": "null"
        etc... etc...
    }
    etc... etc...
}
{
    "category": "Data_Set_2",
    "categoryID": "2ec5e0c1-b839-59a6-8fd5-b09468d6cdd7"
    data: {
        "0001": {
            "value": 9.42343432,
            "timestamp": "null"
        }
        "0002": {
            "value: 13.424234255,
            "timestamp": "null"
        etc... etc...
    }
    etc... etc...
}
etc... etc...
```

I'm aware that this is probably not proper JSON formatting so any help would be great! Only the portion that says "data" needs to be in JSON. The rest can remain however it is.

Comment: What's the problem with `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: What you posted appears to be a list of object literals, which is not valid JSON. It's not clear what you're asking however; if you're talking about JavaScript object initializers, then JSON is irrelevant. If you're talking about text that's supposed to be JSON syntax, then that's not valid; the list needs to be in an array (`[ ]`) with separating commas.

Comment: Both objects with `Data_Set_1` have the same `dataEntryNumber`

Comment: I basically need to restructure my object data to fit the scheme of category -> data ->  [1,2,3,4,5,6] then category2 -> data -> [1,2,3,4,5,6] because currently the objects are not sorted.

Comment: The question title is deceptive. You're basically asking for a reduction to merge several separate objects into one. We'll need more information. Are all these objects different variables or are they inside an array? Any special rules they have to follow? What should the output be, array or object? Any way to fix this at the Source of the data instead of here? What with those duplicates? Filter away or include the same values multiple times?

Comment: Wait, I'm confused now - does this have anything to do with JSON - the textual representation of serialised data?

Comment: The final result I am going for is to have the data portion as a JSON string utilizing the objects I currently have. I have an array of objects and am not quite sure what the most efficient way to parse said array is where each subset of data is incorporated into a single JSON string per category. So essentially the result would include 13 JSON strings (possible in an array?) so that there is one set of data per category (for a total of 13 categories).

Comment: There are duplicates because each category has a set of 6000 data points. (0000 to 6000)

Comment: The question literally has nothing to do with converting a javascript object to json

Comment: I apologize, title updated. I hadn't realized how easy it was to convert a portion of this to JSON with one line. I assumed that I would have to structure it a particular way prior to converting. My new focus is how to parse this array of objects and categorize them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a library called [`blinq`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blinq) (modelled on Microsoft's Linq-to-Objects) that provides a number of useful transformations over iterable sequences. It is very well suited to this kind of transformation.

The transformation can be done as follows:

```
const query = blinq(data)
  .groupBy(item => item.location.categoryID)
  .select(g => ({
    ...g.first().location,
    data: g.aggregate({}, (prev, item) => ({
      ...prev,
      [item.data_objects.dataEntryNumber]: item.data_objects.data
    }))
  }))
const output = [...query]
console.log(output)
```

See below for a working example.

```js
const {
  blinq
} = window.blinq

const data = [{
    "location": {
      "category": "Data_Set_1",
      "categoryID": "66e711cb-81ad-5e22-9fc7-910283924442"
    },
    "data_objects": {
      "dataEntryNumber": "0010",
      "data": {
        "value": 1.4593582153320312,
        "timestamp": "null"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "location": {
      "category": "Data_Set_2",
      "categoryID": "2ec5e0c1-b839-59a6-8fd5-b09468d6cdd7"
    },
    "data_objects": {
      "dataEntryNumber": "0010",
      "data": {
        "value": 1.4593582153320312,
        "timestamp": "null"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "location": {
      "category": "Data_Set_1",
      "categoryID": "66e711cb-81ad-5e22-9fc7-910283924442"
    },
    "data_objects": {
      "dataEntryNumber": "0010",
      "data": {
        "value": 1.4593582153320312,
        "timestamp": "null"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "location": {
      "category": "Data_Set_1",
      "categoryID": "66e711cb-81ad-5e22-9fc7-910283924442"
    },
    "data_objects": {
      "dataEntryNumber": "0011",
      "data": {
        "value": 1.4593582153320312,
        "timestamp": "null"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "location": {
      "category": "Data_Set_3",
      "categoryID": "b905ae3d-1a41-5659-b15e-f305588a0afa"
    },
    "data_objects": {
      "dataEntryNumber": "0010",
      "data": {
        "value": 1.4593582153320312,
        "timestamp": "null"
      }
    }
  }
]

const query = blinq(data)
  .groupBy(item => item.location.categoryID)
  .select(g => ({
    ...g.first().location,
    data: g.aggregate({}, (prev, item) => ({
      ...prev,
      [item.data_objects.dataEntryNumber]: item.data_objects.data
    }))
  }))
const output = [...query]
console.log(output)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/blinq"></script>
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, worked perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to refine your objects. You can do so using map, and assigning the desired keys to the desired values:

```js
var arr = [{
    "location": {
        "category": "Data_Set_1",
        "categoryID": "66e711cb-81ad-5e22-9fc7-910283924442"
    },
    "data_objects": {
        "dataEntryNumber": "0010",
        "data": {
            "value": 1.4593582153320312,
            "timestamp": "null"
        }
    }
},
{
    "location": {
        "category": "Data_Set_2",
        "categoryID": "2ec5e0c1-b839-59a6-8fd5-b09468d6cdd7"
    },
    "data_objects": {
        "dataEntryNumber": "0010",
        "data": {
            "value": 1.4593582153320312,
            "timestamp": "null"
        }
    }
},
{
    "location": {
        "category": "Data_Set_1",
        "categoryID": "66e711cb-81ad-5e22-9fc7-910283924442"
    },
    "data_objects": {
        "dataEntryNumber": "0010",
        "data": {
            "value": 1.4593582153320312,
            "timestamp": "null"
        }
    }
},
{
    "location": {
        "category": "Data_Set_3",
        "categoryID": "b905ae3d-1a41-5659-b15e-f305588a0afa"
    },
    "data_objects": {
        "dataEntryNumber": "0010",
        "data": {
            "value": 1.4593582153320312,
            "timestamp": "null"
        }
    }
}]

console.log(arr.map(({location, data_objects: d}) => ({
  data: {
    [d.dataEntryNumber]: {...d.data}
  },
  ...location
})))
```